# MvvmCross ios UISegmentedControl to show different view controllers

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to display two different views depending on what is selected in a UISegmentedControl. I don't really know where to start. The view(controller) should be shown under the UISegmentedControl.

So assmume I have a MainView(Controller) which contains the segmented control
and two views Child1View(Controller) and Child2View(Controller)

I assume I need two MvxViewControllers (one for each child to be shown) within an MainView(Controller), but I am not sure how I instantiate and show them when I select it via the segmented control.

My MainViewModel has commands to show the child view models (as I have an equiavelent Android implementation using tabs) , but how do I get them to show within the MainView(Controller) which contains the segmented control. I cannot place a UIVIewController in UIViewController in XCode when creating my xib file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying here's what I did

In my MainView(Controller) for each view controllers I needed to instantiate I made a call to CreateViewControllerFor to create my view controllers

```
var child1ViewModelRequest = new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(Child1ViewModel), null, null. null);
child1View = (Child1View) this.CreateViewControllerFor<Child1ViewModel>(child1ViewModelRequest );
```

to show the child view controller, I added a container view which framed the area for the view controller to be displayed, then the following code displayed it

```
currentViewController = (UIViewController)child1View;
this.AddChildViewController(currentViewController);
currentViewController.View.Frame = containerView.Bounds;
containerView.Add(currentViewController.View);
```

Note currentViewController and child1View are member variables of the MainView(Controller)